# Kartik file input yii2

Tags: yii2, fileupload

Использую Kartik file input в фрйемворке yii2
Хочу реализовать пакетную загрузку фотографий с возможность удаления каких то фотографий ДО их загрузки
вот код

```
                <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*','multiple' => true],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/site/upload']),
                    'uploadExtraData' => [
                        'album_id' => 20,
                        'cat_id' => 'Nature'
                    ],
                    'maxFileCount' => 10
                ]
            ])->label('')
            ?>
```

я так понял что сохранять фотки надо в контроллере Site в методе upload,
ноя  не понимаю, как их там отловить
через POST приходит только это

```
'album_id' => 20,
'cat_id' => 'Nature'
```

Может кто то помочь?

Comment: Есть такой глобальный массив у `php` называется `$_FILES` вот там вся инфа о загруженных файлах и ловится .......http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php   ......http://www.php.su/phphttp/?uploads......... http://htmlweb.ru/php/function/$_files.php

Comment: в Yii2 для работы с аплоадом есть свои обертки: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

Прямо из [мануала](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html) про ваш пример:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
....
$model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles')
```